# Timestamp before creating model instance not less than model instance creation timestamp django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, datetime, django-models

I was perfoming some tests on some model so I created a variable `before_creation = datetime.now()`

My model has a field defined as

`date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

During my tests this how am doing it

`before_creation`
`create_model_instance`
then test `before_creation` is less than `mymodel.date_created`, which in my thinking should pass, but its failing with the following message `AssertionError: datetime.datetime (some timestamp) not less than datetime.datetime ((some other timestamp)`. Is this a bug? I have tried switching to timezone with no luck.

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the difference is in microseconds, your database might be truncating those. So if `before_creation` was at 12:00:00.005 and `date_created` was at 12:00:00.008, `date_created` would be returned as 12:00:00. Then you would have `before_creation > date_created`.

Check to make sure that's not the case. Or use:

```
before_creation = datetime.now().replace(microseconds=0)
```

And change your assertion to be less than or equal to.